# Multiple DAG runs after one finished successfully

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

One of the Tasks I have in my Airflow DAG is exporting data from BQ to files (I use wildcard `*` in the URI) and I see that at the end of the specific Task of exporting to files, it starts additional runs of the DAG and fails in the first Task.

It seems that the number of runs depends on the number of files it exports (when I changed the URI to be without wildcard it started a single extra run right after it managed to export).

Why is this happening? What can I do differently to avoid these multiple runs?

That's how it looks in airflow tree:

[image: how it looks in airflow tree]

```py
import datetime
import json
from airflow import utils
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from google.cloud import bigquery, pubsub_v1


def publish_message(**context):
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

    topic_path = publisher.topic_path('a', 'a')

    data_str = json.dumps(context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='set_params', key='request_params'))
    data = data_str.encode("utf-8")

    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    print(future.result())

    print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}.")


def set_params(params, **context):
    query_params = {}
    file_format = 'json'
    compression = 'gzip'
    params_fixed = json.loads(params.replace("\'", "\""))
    for sub in params_fixed['params']:
        if sub["param_name"] == 'file_format':
            file_format = sub["param_value"]
        elif sub["param_name"] == 'compression':
            compression = sub["param_value"]
        else:
            query_params[sub["param_name"]] = sub["param_value"]
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='file_format', value=file_format)
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='compression', value=compression)
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='query_params', value=query_params)
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='request_params', value=params_fixed)
    

with DAG(dag_id="export_data_to_gcs",
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
    
    my_params = '{{dag_run.conf}}'
    
    set_params = PythonOperator(
        task_id='set_params',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=set_params,
        op_kwargs={'params': my_params},
        dag=dag,
    )  
    
    execute_sql = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='execute_sql',
        sql='/SQL/sql_query.sql',
        bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        dag=dag,
    )

    publish_message = PythonOperator(
        task_id='publish_message',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=publish_message,
        dag=dag,
    )
   
   
start >> set_params >> execute_sql >> publish_message
```

Comment: Can you include the DAG and tasks definition code? Otherwise it's difficult to understand what's happening

Comment: @vinsce i added the code. please notice that my dag is triggered by cloud function that pass queryparams. And as i said, after execure sql is done, another dags starts running..

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is in the DAG it self, it is more likely to be on the trigger side (cloud function). You should try to trigger the DAG manually (e.g. Web UI or CLI) and see if the problem persists

Comment: Already checked. The same thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when I switched to another gcp environment